# Unable to Redirect URL in ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, webmethod, pagemethods

I am using PageMethods in my ASP.NET (WebForms) app on my front end to call a c# function on the back end that deletes a row from my database. The deleting part works but I am unable to redirect the url afterwords from my current .aspx file to a new one called StartPage.aspx. Essentially, I want to make it so after a button press the url changes from UpdateNetEvent.aspx?ID=[Number] to StartPage.aspx.

My HTML for the button is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="eventFormResolveBtn" runat="server" Text="Resolve NetEvent" OnClientClick="resolveClicked()" style="background-color:forestgreen;"/>
```

And the corresponding Javascript function call is:

```
function resolveClicked() {

            try {

                var currentRowID = document.getElementById('<%=eventFormCurrentRowID.ClientID%>').value;

                PageMethods.resolveData(currentRowID, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

                function OnSucceeded(result) {
                    window.location = result.d;
                }

                function OnFailed(error) {
                    alert("An error occured on resolveClicked()");
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                return err;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Additionally, the WebMethod call on the backend is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string resolveData(string CurrentRowID)
    {
       try
        {
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("deleteNetEventRow", sqlConn);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID", Convert.ToInt32(CurrentRowID));

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlConn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
            return "StartPage.aspx";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());     // Add a log helper to display errors here
            return "Error in resolveData WebMethod";
        }
    }
```

The SQLCommand call and execution works perfectly but I am not able to redirect to another .aspx page afterwords.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens? Did you examine `result.d`?

Comment: When I debug in chrome result.d is getting the correct string value and the call is made but nothing happens afterwords, it sits on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
```

you can return the url of the server like below :

```
result.d="http://localhost/StartPage.aspx"

function OnSucceeded(result) {
         window.location.href = result.d;
}
```

Comment: When I used this method and changed return "StartPage.aspx" to return "http://localhost/StartPage.aspx" I am now getting a 404 Not Found Error

Comment: what is the url of your page initial can you copy paste it

Comment: localhost:(port-number)/StartPage.aspx

Comment: ok so while return from you code part the url shoud be like result.d="http://localhost:portnumber/StartPage.aspx"

Comment: Interesting when I use chrome debug and step through the process it still gives me 404 Not Found but when I use the web form without chrome debugger open it just stays on the same page

Comment: No it still does not go to the StartPage.aspx

Comment: have you tried directly redirecting from the code part

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157507/discussion-between-shivshankar-namdev-and-frankthetank).